# Why do breakpoints in my function with a yield do not break?

Tags: python

I am writing Python in VSCode. I have a file with two functions, and a second file that calls those function. When I put breakpoints in one of the functions, the breakpoint does not hit.

Here is test2.py that has the two functions...

```
def func1():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

def func2():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
```

Here is test1.py for which the debugger is being launched from...

```
import test2

test2.func1()
test2.func2()
```

When I put a breakpoint on the for loop in both func1 and func2, then run the debugger from test1.py, the breakpoint for func1 is never hit, but the breakpoint in func2 is hit.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually advanced the generator, so it set up a generator instance for `func1`, but didn't begin executing it. If you want it to run out the generator, iterate the result of calling `func1`, e.g. replace:

```
test2.func1()
```

with:

```
# Extracts and prints all items
for x in test2.func1():
    print(x)

# Or to extract and print a single item:
print(next(test2.func1()))
```

Answer (score 2):

`func1` is a generator function. It returns a generator; it does *not* automatically execute the `for` loop. The first time you call `next` on the generator, it will execute up to the first `yield` statement, which produces the return value for `next`. Each subsequent time you call `next` on the same generator, it resumes where it left off and continues executing until the next `yield` statement (in this case, in the next iteration of the loop).

So you would need to write something like

```
g = func1()
next(g)
```

to hit your breakpoint for the first time.

Comment: but why does it not hit the breakpoint when you add another 'next(g)' call?

Comment: @koegl  It should.  In my test it hits the breakpoint on every call to `next(g)` (or next(x) in my own test code).  If you put the call to next(g) in a loop, and use Step In, it will step into the generator to get the next yield call, then step out to the loop that called next, and then back into the generator function again.